# Preimage of sets, complement of sets, continuity of functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

I just got some simple questions in real analysis regarding preimage and complement of sets and continuity.

1. Suppose $f:X\to Y$,
   then does $f^{-1} (Y\setminus F)=f^{-1} (Y)\setminus f^{-1} (F)=X\setminus f^{-1} (F)$ always hold? But why the first equality is true?
2. Can we rewrite the definition of continuity of a function in metric space as 
    $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $a \in X \Longleftrightarrow $ given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that$f(B^{0}(a,\delta))\subset B^0(f(a), \epsilon)$, where $B^0$ represents open balls.

Thank you.

Comment: If I say your question is brilliant, that's a compliment (with an "i"), but if I add something to your question, thereby making it _complete_, then what I add is a complement (with an "e").  Just remember the resemblance to the spelling of "complete" to remember which is which.  I corrected the spelling in the question. $\qquad$

Comment: Oh yes.. sorry... Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first equality is true:
   \begin{align*}
   f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)&=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Y\setminus F\}\\
   &=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Y\text{ and }f(x)\not\in F\}\\
   &=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Y\}\cap\{x\in X:f(x)\not\in F\}\\
   &=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Y\}\cap\left(X\setminus\{x\in X:f(x)\in F\}\right)\\
   &=f^{-1}(Y)\cap\left(X\setminus f^{-1}(F)\right)\\
   &=f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}(F).
   \end{align*}
   The second equality is also true because $f$ being a function implies $f^{-1}(Y)=X$. Note that in general the preimage acts as we would wish with most set operations.
2. This is true. I guess your definition of continuity in a metric space goes like this: we say $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $a\in X$ if
   $$
   \forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x\in X,d_X(x,a)<\delta\implies d_Y(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon.
   $$
   But the condition
   $$
   \forall x\in X,d_X(x,a)<\delta\implies d_Y(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon
   $$
   is readily seen to be equivalent to
   $$
   f(B^0(a,\delta))\subset B^0(f(a),\epsilon).
   $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both. To see why the first is true, observe that $x\in f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)$ if and only if $f(x)\in Y\setminus F$ if and only if $x\notin f^{-1}(F)$.